# Why gradient of vector normalize is not zero along both X,Y axes

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis

Vector normalization for 2D vector is defined as $v / ||v||$.

Thus gradient, I take here x axis is defined as
$d(x/sqrt(x^2+y^2))/dx = y^2/((x^2+y^2)^(3/2))$

I lack interpretation of the result. Along x axis, giving that y = 0, we get zero gradient which makes sense:

```
(1, 0) -normalized->  (1, 0)
(2, 0) -normalized->  (1, 0)
(3, 0) -normalized->  (1, 0)
```

so, whatever is the X value, the resulting X does not change and thus gradient is zero.

However, using the same logic, X == 0, changing Y:

```
(0, 1) -normalized->  (0, 1)
(0, 2) -normalized->  (0, 1)
(0, 3) -normalized->  (0, 1)
```

the resulting X never changes either, however gradient is a hyperbola. Why is it so, what do I miss here?

Thank you.